# HTML,CSS,JS calendar adding

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I have this search bar here on my web page, but when I click on the calendar nothing happens, do you know what should I add there, so the calendar would pop up somehow?

[search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2SH7.png)

Also here is a script for the search bar:

```
    <!-- Search -->
        <script>
        $(window).ready(function(){
              var nowTemp = new Date();
              var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
              var checkin = $('#checkin').datepicker({
                onRender: function(date) {
                  return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
              }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
                if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
                  var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                  checkout.setValue(newDate);
                }
                checkin.hide();
                $('#checkout')[0].focus();
              }).data('datepicker');
              var checkout = $('#checkout').datepicker({
                onRender: function(date) {
                  return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
              }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
                checkout.hide();
              }).data('datepicker');
            });
        </script>
```

Here it's one div for check in for example and there is also this calendar, but it's only glyphicon:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkin" placeholder="Check in">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is enough for helping me, if it's not I will just add more code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Jquery ui can help you.
Here is the solution: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger